# npm - Compile typescript files in npm build script

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm trying to create a build script using just npm without grunt or gulp.

Most things are working apart from concatenating typescript.

I can compile single typescript files but I have a number of separate files I need to concatenate and then compile.

I'm using the concat-cli mobule but it doesn't seem to concatenate files and just outputs the first file in the folder.

What the best way to concatenate typescript files.

```
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",

      "scripts": {
        "scss": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o src/assets/css src/assets/sass/main.scss",
        "compile:ts": "tsc --outDir ./src/assets/js/ --module commonjs ./src/app/**/*.ts",
        "concat:ts": "concat-cli --files src/app/**/*.ts --output dist/js/output.ts",
        "serve": "browser-sync start --server --files 'src/assets/css/, src/assets/js/*.js, **/*.html, !node_modules/**/*.html'",
        "watch:css": "onchange 'src/assets/sass/*.scss' -- npm run scss",
        "watch:js": "onchange 'src/app/**/*.js' -- npm run jshint",
        "watch:ts": "onchange 'src/app/**/*.ts' -- npm run concat:ts",
        "watch:all": "npm-run-all -p serve watch:css watch:js watch:images",
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
        "concat": "0.0.1-security",
        "concat-cli": "^4.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
        "onchange": "^2.5.0",
        "typescript": "^1.8.10",
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> What the best way to concatenate typescript files.

Use modules and use a module loader like webpack. QuickStart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

## Why

Blindly concatenating JS file without using a module system will be rife with `ReferenceError: Variable not defined` and `TypeError : undefined is ....`. There are also other maintainability reasons. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

Comment: Can I use globs in the webpack.config.js. I have an app folder with controllers, directives, services and filters folders for my angularjs code. So I have different typescript files that I need to compile if I use `entry: './src/app/**/*.ts',` i get an error